# How can I detect slow filesystems on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems

For my shell configuration I want to know if I am on a slow directory (e.g. sshfs or cifs mount).

This allows me to skip some actions, like looking for changes in repositories via Zsh's `vcs_info`.

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with the following function, which first tries `df -T` and
looks up the file type via `mount`, if `df -T` is not available (e.g. on
busybox systems):

```
_is_slow_file_system() {
  df_T=$(df -T . 2>/dev/null) || true
  if [[ $df_T == '' ]]; then
    # 'df -T' might not be available (busybox, diskstation).
    # 'stat -f' does not detect cifs (type UNKNOWN).
    # fs_type=$(stat -f . | grep -o 'Type:.*' | cut -f2 -d\ )
    mount_point="$(df . | awk 'END {print $NF}')"
    fs_type=$(mount | awk '$3 == "'$mount_point'" { print $5 }')
  else
    fs_type=$(echo $df_T | tail -n1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d\  2>/dev/null)
  fi

  case $fs_type in
    (sshfs|nfs|cifs|fuse.bup-fuse) return 0 ;;
    (*) return 1;;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple just run this in terminal

```
cat /proc/filesystems
```